# Array equality / inequality

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why these JavaScript Array inequality comparisons evaluate to true?

```
[""] !== [""]

[1] !== [1]

[] !== []


[""] != [""]

[1] != [1]

[] != []
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Well, it would be the same in most languages.

Comment: myHouse and yourHouse are both houses but myHouse !== yourHouse -> true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`===` is **strict** equality.
When comparing objects, it will only return true if both sides refer to the same object.

`[]` and `[]` are two different (though equivalent) objects, so it returns false.

---

`==` is loose equality.

It will attempt to coerce both operands to the same type, as described in the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3).

However, it too compares objects by referential identity.

Comment: Note that comparing string literals will yield true ("a" === "a"), but comparing String objects will yield false: new String("a") === new String("a"). I thereby conclude that string literals are not treated as objects, and 'interned' in a similar way to Java language.

Comment: @normc: No.  Unlike Java, Javascript has a string _primitive_ type, just like numbers.  `new String("a")` boxes it to an object.  For example, `var a = "a"; a.b = 2; alert(a.b); // undefined`

Comment: @normc: Boxed string objects are almost never used; all string operations return primitives.